# can't use useDispatch inside an async map function, inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-hooks, async-await

I'm trying to update each 'orderItem' in my database, for that I'm using useDispatch() inside a map function and inside a useEffect.

Everything seems correct, I've another code like this, that is working but the only difference is that this one is inside a .map() async.

Is using a map async function the problem? How can I get solve this problem ?

```
useEffect(() => {

    if(order && order.isPaid) {
      order.orderItems.map(async (item) => {
        try {
      const updatedDeck = await updateDeck({
          _id: item.premiumDeck,
          learningProfileId: learningProfileId,
          isActive: true
        }).unwrap();
        refetch();
      // console.log(item._id)
      console.log(updatedDeck);
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err?.data?.message || err.error);
    }
   });
   }
  
  }, [order, learningProfileId, updateDeck, refetch]);
```

The code doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't update the "isActive" to true neither.
I tried to put the try catch outside the map function. I tried also to run this function outside the useEffect. On both cases, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should use `array.forEach` to iterate an array and issue side-effects. Other than this, what exactly is the issue or problem? What `useDispatch` hook are you referring to? What is `updateDeck`? We may need a bit more detail and context. See [mcve].